# How to mount a disk image with automator or Applescript and without hdiutil?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, mount

An Automator workflow that mounts a disk image on when I drag and drop the dmg file onto it is easy: [image]

Instead of dragging and dropping the dmg file I want to double click the created workflow and have it mount a specific file. I've tried using "Set Value of Variable" to the path of the dmg, "Open Finder Items", and "Get Selected Folder Items", nothing works.

I can do it with the command line as:

```bsh
hdiutil mount disk_image_name.dmg
```

I've also tried with the Applescript:

```
    on run {input, parameters}

        tell application "DiskImageMounter"
            open "path/disk_image_name.dmg"
        end tell
    end run
```

But after mounting the disk image as expected, Automator freezes for about 15 seconds and gives the below Syntax Error.

[image]

The reason I want to avoid using hdituil is the disk images are encrypted. When using the Automator mount tool the password is done in Apple's dialog box. Using hdiutil I end up passing the password as stdin.

```
printf '%s\0' "$PASSPHRASE" | hdiutil attach $LOCATION -stdinpass
```

Comment: Is the some good reason you cannot just double click the target DMG file in Finder? That will prompt for the password and mount it if the proper password is given.

Comment: Don't use _DiskImageMounter_.  This is one instance where you should use _Finder_ as it is more reliable (which is the **only** time this is ever true).

Comment: @user3439894 I can't just double click because there is more to the workflow than just mounting the image.

Comment: @CJK I tried and Applescript with tell "Finder" but it cannot open dmg files.

Comment: @OrigamiEye I suggest to use `hdiutil mount ...` with a p12 but no password (cert based disk image protection with the keychain which requires a password only once). Takes ~3 minutes work in the shell and requires *run shell script* > `hdiutil mount /path/to/disk_image_name.dmg` in a workflow only

Comment: You couldn't open it with _Finder_ because you most likely had an improper file reference. It does, and is the best thing to, handle `.dmg` files (in terms of AppleScript).

Answer (score 2):

I would use `hdiutil ...` instead of other methods but with an image protected by a certificate instead of a password. This is similar as to building an encrypted image with a password **and** a recovery key (based on a cert) - without password though:

1. Create a temporary cert folder and cd into it:

   ```
   mkdir ~/certsecdmg
   cd ~/certsecdmg
   ```
2. Create a root CA if you don't have one already:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -des3 -out casecdmg.key 4096
   openssl req -new -x509 -days 7300 -key casecdmg.key -out casecdmg.crt
   ```

   Fill in all proposed fields.
3. Create a password protected certificate signing request:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -des3 -out secdmgbuild.key 4096 
   openssl req -new -key secdmgbuild.key -out secdmgbuild.csr
   ```

   Fill in all proposed fields.
4. Create the signed certificate in PEM format

   ```
   openssl x509 -req -days 7300 -in secdmgbuild.csr -CA casecdmg.crt -CAkey casecdmg.key -set_serial 01 -out secdmgbuild.crt
   ```
5. Convert the signed certificate to DER format

   ```
   openssl x509 -in secdmgbuild.crt -inform pem -out secdmgbuild.der -outform der
   ```
6. Bundle the PEM certificate and private key into a PKCS#12 package

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in secdmgbuild.crt -inkey secdmgbuild.key -out secdmgbuild.p12
   ```
7. Use `hdiutil` with the *-certificate* options to create an encrypted volume (example only):

   ```
   hdiutil create -type SPARSE -encryption aes-256 -certificate ~/certsecdmg/secdmgbuild.der -fs HFS+J -volname "SecureImage" -size 100m ~/Desktop/SecureImage
   ```
8. Import *secdmgbuild.p12* in your keychain
9. Double-click *SecureImage.sparseimage*, enter: *password of step 3/always allow* to always allow access for diskimages-helper.
10. Create a new Automator workflow, adding a Run Shell Script action with the following command:

    ```
    hdiutil mount ~/Desktop/SecureImage.sparseimage
    ```

    <sup>(please apply paths as needed)</sup>

    This simple Automator workflow works as "workflow" and "app".
11. Add further actions as required.
12. Save the content of the folder *certsecdmg* at a secure place and remove it afterwards.

Comment: @user3439894 it may require some input which depends on "@user3439894 I can't just double click **because there is more to the workflow than just mounting the image**. – OrigamiEye 8 hours ago"

Comment: @user3439894 Another quote: "Instead of dragging and dropping the dmg file I want to double click the created workflow and have it mount a specific file." The simple workflow consisting of the "run shell script ..." action only, works as workflow as well as app (both tested).

Comment: This is interesting but not what I was looking for.

Comment: I wanted to acknowledge your efforts and provide a reason why I won't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The code in my AppleScript was causing problems.

The full automator flow is 2 Apple Scripts, one to set the variable for the file location and another to run it.

The first script:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set output to "NameOfImage"

    return output
end run
```

The next one

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set imagePath to "Macintosh HD:Rest of Path:" & (item 1 of input) & ".dmg"
    tell application "DiskImageMounter"
        try
            open alias imagePath
        end try
    end tell
end run
```

Running the previous code in Script Editor produced an error message instead of timing out.

> error "DiskImageMounter got an error: Connection is invalid." number
>   -609

I don't know why a try statement fixed it or why it needs the alias, but there is not much information available on AppleScript.